# Is there a way to print stdout as it is outputted?

Tags: python, plumbum

If if I ran

```
from plumbum import local
local['ping']['google.com']()
```

It would just hang indefinitely because ping executes forever.

Is there a way to print the output of ping as it executes, perhaps in a generator or something, like

```
for a in local['ping']['google.com']():
    print a
```

Comment: This is way too broad. What is `local`? Is it your local variables? If so, what's `ping`? You should really read [mcve].

Comment: @MorganThrapp , `local` is presumably [`plumbum.local`](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/local_commands.html#local-commands).

Comment: @MorganThrapp: I think it is in the tags. `plumbum` seems to be some kind of command line tool for python and in its context the question seems to make sense.

Comment: In the context of plumbum this would make complete sense but I'll add some imports. Please revert your downvote, this is a useful question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/local_commands.html#background-and-foreground), this should work:

```
from plumbum import local, FG

local["ping"]["google.com"] & FG
```

Comment: do you know how I would go about storing the output? & FG uses parent streams and I don't want to write some output buffering hack.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in conjunction with remote machines. (Or at least with `ParamikoMachine` – maybe because the latter doesn't support piping?)